# Websphere 6.1 UTF-8 Encoded URL Parameters

Tags: java, character-encoding, websphere

I am invoking a Servlet which is running in a **Websphere 6.1** using the following encoded UTF-8 URL:

http://mydomain.com/testingUtf?first=%E3%81%82

Then when I get the request parameter using 
**req.getParameter("first");**
from my servlet the value is: **ã** instead of **あ**.

What am I missing? Why am I getting that character?

It appears as if **Websphere** is applying an invalid character encoding to the query parameter.

When I do the same test with **Jetty** it work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your HTTP request, add the "Content-Type" header. Set it to the proper MIME value (text/xml, text/plain, etc), then specify the encoding, like so:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

WebSphere 7 properly parses our UTF-8 encoded parameters using this. Should probably work for 6.1 too.